# Swift - Using created plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am creating an API Keys plist for my application and I am trying to figure out how to create a function that stores these plist values in variables that can be used in my other files. My `ApiKeys.plist` looks like this:

Root - Dictionary - (blank)

- Parse_App_Id - String - xxxxxxx
- Parse_Client_Id - String - xxxxxx

Then I have an `ApiKeys.swift` file where my function is stored:

```
import Foundation

func valueForAPIKey(#keyname:String) -> String {

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ApiKeys", ofType: "plist")

    let plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let parseAppId:String = plist?.objectForKey("Parse_App_Id") as String
    let parseClientId:String = plist?.objectForKey("Parse_Client_Id") as String


    return parseAppId && parseClientID

}
```

Side note: I used a tutorial to build this function and I'm curious if this is the best way to set up a function to store two plist keys.

**First error** comes on the `return` line. Can't invoke `&&` argument list of type '(String, String)'

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


            Parse.setApplicationId(valueForAPIKey.(keyname: "ParseAppId")), clientKey: valueForAPIKey.(keyname:"ParseClientId"))
            PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

        return true
    }
```

**Second Error:** Expected ',' separator at valueForAPIKey.`(`keyname: "ParseAppID")

I'm very new to the `plist` concepts so please excuse my clear errors and misdirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion I think, not only with the plist thing.

First, your method expect to return a String.

Either your return your results as a single String :

```
func valueForAPIKey(#keyname:String) -> String {
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ApiKeys", ofType: "plist")

    let plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let parseAppId:String = plist?.objectForKey("Parse_App_Id") as String
    let parseClientId:String = plist?.objectForKey("Parse_Client_Id") as String

    return "\(parseAppId) \(parseClientID)"
}
```

Or you choose to return a tuple (or an array), and you'll access the element 0 or 1 depending on which one you need.

```
func valueForAPIKey(#keyname:String) -> (String, String) {
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ApiKeys", ofType: "plist")

    let plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let parseAppId:String = plist?.objectForKey("Parse_App_Id") as String
    let parseClientId:String = plist?.objectForKey("Parse_Client_Id") as String

    return (parseAppId, parseClientID)
}
```

**However, since you are using a parameter `keyname`, why don't you use it ?**

```
func valueForAPIKey(#keyname:String) -> String {
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ApiKeys", ofType: "plist")

    let plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let id : String = plist?.objectForKey(keyname) as String

    return id
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it like so :

```
Parse.setApplicationId(valueForAPIKey("Parse_App_Id"), clientKey : valueForAPIKey("Parse_Client_Id"))
```